# PlayFramework working with high load of REST api calls in parallel

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a play-framework micro-service lets call it service A (runs on Kubernetes if it matters), and there is another micro-service in the cluster that calls service A api ALLOT, and at some point service A pods crash and liveness readiness also fail with timeout, but when I disable the service who create the requests, service A become stable again.

im trying to understand cause isn't play supposed to handle the load out of the box or I need to configure something?

I thought there is a pull and if there is more calls it will just block them...cause service who creates the call have retries and its ok to be blocked.

so my point is im trying to understand if its possible play need to be configured for high load somehow or the problem coming from somewhere else.

thought maybe there is exception thrown during the calls but nothing in the logs of some sort of failure during the api call processing.

please help if you have an idea, thanks!!

Comment: It's impossible to help you without more details about your application. Likely you are using blocking call without a proper ExecutionContext. It also depends what you mean by a lot of queries. At some point you still have to scale.

Comment: Interesting read for you: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools#Understanding-Play-thread-pools

Comment: I don't think Play offers load balancing by default. You should do some configuration.  Whether you decide to use Apache Http Server or nginx or lighttpd you should check this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/HTTPServer